# How to connect HTML POST with Mongo using node

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, post, express

I am just making a simple blog application with Node, Express and MongoDB. I have a blogPost schema and I'm able to successfully GET and POST with Chrome's Postman. Now I am just trying to create a simple HTML form so I can create a blog post. But I'm not sure how to connect it with MongoDB. Below is some of the code.

index.html

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

server.js

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.route('/blogPosts')

  .post(function(req, res) {
    var blogPost = new BlogPost();

    blogPost.postbody = req.body.postbody;
    blogPost.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({ message: blogPost.postbody + "created"})
    });
  })

  .get(function(req, res) {
    BlogPost.find(function(err, posts) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      res.json(posts);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add action in your html code :

```
<form class="" action="/blogPosts" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="postbody"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

So ,in server.js , you need to use bodyParser in your express instance.

```
// Example
var app  = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true});
.....
//
var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.route('/blogPosts')

  .post(function(req, res) {
    var blogPost = new BlogPost();

    blogPost.postbody = req.body.postbody;
    blogPost.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({ message: blogPost.postbody + "created"})
    });
  })
```